# Joining accessories with products from a order

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

These are my tables:

```
Order 
-Id PK
-Timestamp
-Seller
-Buyer

OrderItem
-Id PK
-OrderId FK
-ProductId FK
-AccessoryId FK

Products
-Id PK
-Name
-Price

Accessories
-Id PK
-Name
-Price

ProductAccessories
-Id PK
-ProductId FK
-AccessoryId FK
```

Now I have the following query to get all orders that are at least 1 year old:

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[Timestamp]
      ,[Seller]
      ,[Buyer]
  FROM [dbo].[Order]
  WHERE Timestamp <= getdate()-365
```

Now to my question. After running this query I need help with another one. **I want to get all the Accessories that has a forgein key to a Product that was part of a specific OrderId retrieved by the query above**.

I can't get my head around how many joins I have to do here.

Comment: You should also tag database management system that you are using (SQL Server, MySQL, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires lots of `JOIN`s, but I think this is what you want

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM [dbo].[Order] o
  JOIN OrderItem oi ON oi.OrderId = o.Id
  JOIN Products p ON p.Id = oi.ProductId
  JOIN ProductAccessories pa ON pa.ProductId = p.Id
  JOIN Accessories a ON a.Id = pa.AccessoryId
  WHERE o.[Timestamp] <= DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work! Though I had to replace the last line with (for example) WHERE o.Id = 1

Comment: @Nisse32 Good to know. You should accept the answer (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote.